# Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute even though the collection was modified exclusively in lock statements

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following base code. The `ActionMonitor` can be used by anyone, in whatever setting, regardless of single-thread or multi-thread.

```
using System;
public class ActionMonitor
{
    public ActionMonitor()
    {

    }


    private object _lockObj = new object();

    public void OnActionEnded()
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            IsInAction = false;
            foreach (var trigger in _triggers)
                trigger();
            _triggers.Clear();
        }
    }

    public void OnActionStarted()
    {
        IsInAction = true;
    }

    private ISet<Action> _triggers = new HashSet<Action>();
    public void ExecuteAfterAction(Action action)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            if (IsInAction)
                _triggers.Add(action);
            else
                action();
        }
    }

    public bool IsInAction
    {
       get;private set;

    }
}
```

On exactly one occasion, when I examined a crash on client's machine, an exception was thrown at:

> System.Core: System.InvalidOperationException Collection was modified;enumeration operation may not execute. at
>
> System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`1.Enumerator.MoveNext() at
>
> WPFApplication.ActionMonitor.OnActionEnded()

My reaction when seeing this stack trace: this is unbelievable! This must be a .Net bug!.

Because although `ActionMonitor` can be used in multithreading setting, but the crash above shouldn't occur-- all the `_triggers` ( the collection) modification happens inside a `lock` statement. This guarantees that one cannot iterate over the collection *and* modifying it at the same time.

And, if `_triggers` happened to contain an `Action` that involves `ActionMonitor`, then the we might get a deadlock, but it would never crash.

I have seen this crash exactly once, so I can't reproduce the problem at all. But base on my understanding of multithreading and `lock` statement, this exception can never have occurred.

Do I miss something here? Or is it known that .Net can behave it a very quirky way, when it involves `System.Action`?

Comment: @CodeCaster, the `ActionMonitor` is **the actual code**.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast, what I post is the actual code. No static `_lockObj`, no casting `_triggers.ToArray()`

Comment: What calls `ExecuteAfterAction` and can it be reached by the `trigger()` call? Because the one thing locks definitely won't help you with is if the thread doing the enumeration is *also* the thread doing the modification. locks are reentrant.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, like I mention above, even if `ActionMonitor` can be reached by `trigger()` call, then the worst we can get is a deadlock situation, there is no way for any thread to get under `lock` statement while another thread is already under it, no?

Comment: The **same** thread can take the lock multiple times - that's what my previous comment was trying to tell you.

Comment: The simple explanation is that ExecuteAfterAction() ran on the same thread as OnActionEnded().  The lock statement is re-entrant on the same thread.  So "regardless of single-thread or multi-thread" is a bug, not a feature.  WPF is a hint as well, the lock statement does not actually block the UI thread.  Blocking that thread is illegal, the CLR has a dispatcher loop to ensure no deadlock can occur.  So, say, an Invoke() call will complete even though the lock is held.

Comment: To visualize, `lock (_lockObj) { lock (_lockObj) { stuff(); } }` would *not* deadlock but execute `stuff()` unhindered.

Comment: 99% of the time when you think "this must be a bug in someone else's code" -- it's not. Get out of the habit of blaming others for your problems and you'll find your own problems sooner!

Comment: Also the fact that IsInAction is read and written both in locks and outside of locks is almost certainly wrong. `triggers` is correctly protected by the locks, but what guarantees that reads to `IsInAction` are not cached and writes are not delayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't shield your code against the following call:

```
private static ActionMonitor _actionMonitor;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    _actionMonitor = new ActionMonitor();
    _actionMonitor.OnActionStarted();
    _actionMonitor.ExecuteAfterAction(Foo1);
    _actionMonitor.ExecuteAfterAction(Foo2);
    _actionMonitor.OnActionEnded();

    Console.ReadLine();
}
private static void Foo1()
{
    _actionMonitor.OnActionStarted();
    //Notice that if you would call _actionMonitor.OnActionEnded(); here instead of _actionMonitor.OnActionStarted(); - you would get a StackOverflow Exception
    _actionMonitor.ExecuteAfterAction(Foo3);
}
private static void Foo2()
{

}
private static void Foo3()
{

}
```

FYI - that's the scenario `Damien_The_Unbeliever` is talking about in the comments.

To fix that issue the only 2 things that come in mind are

1. Don't call it like this, it's your class and your code is calling it so make sure you stick to your own rules
2. Get a copy of the `_trigger` list and enumarate this

About point 1, you could track if `OnActionEnded` is running and throw an exception if `OnActionStarted` is called while running:

```
private bool _isRunning = false;
public void OnActionEnded()
{
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
        try
        {
            _isRunning = true;

            IsInAction = false;
            foreach (var trigger in _triggers)
                trigger();
            _triggers.Clear();
        }
        finally
        {
            _isRunning = false;
        }
    }
}

public void OnActionStarted()
{
    lock (_lockObj)
    {        
        if (_isRunning)
            throw new NotSupportedException();

        IsInAction = true;
    }
}
```

About point 2, how about this

```
public class ActionMonitor
{
    public ActionMonitor()
    {

    }

    private object _lockObj = new object();

    public void OnActionEnded()
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            IsInAction = false;

            var tmpTriggers = _triggers;
            _triggers = new HashSet<Action>();
            foreach (var trigger in tmpTriggers)
                trigger();

            //have to decide what to do if _triggers isn't empty here, we could use a while loop till its empty
            //so for example

            while (true)
            {    
                var tmpTriggers = _triggers;
                _triggers = new HashSet<Action>();
                if (tmpTriggers.Count == 0)
                    break;

                foreach (var trigger in tmpTriggers)
                    trigger();
            }
        }
    }

    public void OnActionStarted()
    {
        lock (_lockObj) //fix the error @EricLippert talked about in comments
            IsInAction = true;
    }

    private ISet<Action> _triggers = new HashSet<Action>();
    public void ExecuteAfterAction(Action action)
    {
        lock (_lockObj)
        {
            if (IsInAction)
                _triggers.Add(action);
            else
                action();
        }
    }

    public bool IsInAction
    {
       get;private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I can reproduce the problem with your sample. May I know how it could have been fixed?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. However two things come to my mind : 1) why throws an exception if 'IsInAction' is set with the same value ,2) I am thinking of using 'ConcurrentQueue' instead of 'HashSet' to store a list of 'Action'. Do you think that's a good idea ?

Comment: 1) was a brain fart sorry - I fixed it - forgot that you are setting `IsInAction = false` at the start of `OnActionEnded` - your problem is that you are calling `OnActionStarted` while its running and idea 1 was to make it obvious that this is a problem 2) `ConcurrentQueue` wont solve the problem since your problem is reproducable with one thread - but yes, a `ConcurrentQueue` is preferable over a simple `HashSet` with `lock`

Comment: ConcurrentQueue doesn't have collection is modified exception problem , so it should be fine right , or am I missing something here ?

Comment: @Graviton - seems you were correct - didnt know about that sry - but this doesnt fail - https://dotnetfiddle.net/C5YdRF

Answer (score 1):

> This guarantees that one cannot iterate over the collection and modifying it at the same time.

No. You have a reentrancy problem.

Consider what happens if *inside* the call to `trigger` (same thread, so lock is already held), you modify the collection:

`csharp
   foreach (var trigger in _triggers)
       trigger(); // _triggers modified in here`

<del>In fact if you look at your full callstack, you will be able to find the frame that is enumerating the collection.</del> (by the time the exception happens, the code that modified the collection has been popped off the stack)

Comment: By the time they're looking at the callstack, the modification code has been popped off - the error is raised back at the enumerator, not at the point of modification.

Comment: *Consider what happens if inside the call to trigger (same thread, so lock is already held), you modify the collection:*-- if such thing ever happens, then it will be a deadlock, and not a collection cannot be modified exception, right?

Comment: @Graviton: no; the lock is a recursive (reentrant) lock, meaning that once you've acquired the lock, you can lock it as many more times as you like on that same thread, and the lock is only actually released when you have released the lock as many times as you acquired it. Only a different thread that tries to acquire the lock will be blocked until the lock is released.